# How do you manage your inventory of spot instances on AWS with Ansible

Tags: ansible, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Ansible, with some experience in Chef. I am considering learn and use Ansible to manage environments.

I was wondering, what would be the best practice to manage inventory of AWS spot instances?

For example, when a spot instance is shut down the old IP is not relevant anymore in the inventory of hosts.

Are there any other alternative approaches for the use case of elastic environments?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for *Dynamic Inventory*

Please look into [`ec2.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) and [`ec2.ini`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) of Ansible, and also the [`Dynamic Inventory`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) docs of Ansible are very good for understanding how to manage your AWS inventory.

Comment: thank you, so for example if I give to some instances specific tag, I could access the dynamic inventory file and take the instances under specific tag  ? is it best practice?

Comment: @Berlin Yeah, why not.  The tag is called a host group :)